# How to turn object with values into an array with values

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I need to essentially parse the JSON and make it into a array with the same values to then pass into my PostgreSQL database using a `pool.query(message, values)` in which values should be an array if multiple are present, currently my object looks like this

```
{
  symbol: 'AAPL',
  beta: 1.1792937836342379,
  debtEquity: 1.19,
  dividendYield: 0.006304622435881964,
  peRatio: 37.02,
  employees: 142011,
  priceBook: 24.66992282382262,
  psRatio: 7.9,
  putCallRatio: 0.845692355591619,
  revenueShare: 15.22,
  enterpriseValueRevenue: 8.17,
  nextEarnings: '2020-10-18',
  eps: 3.3888
}
```

but I need it to look like this:

```
[
  symbol: 'AAPL',
  beta: 1.1792937836342379,
  debtEquity: 1.19,
  dividendYield: 0.006304622435881964,
  peRatio: 37.02,
  employees: 142011,
  priceBook: 24.66992282382262,
  psRatio: 7.9,
  putCallRatio: 0.845692355591619,
  revenueShare: 15.22,
  enterpriseValueRevenue: 8.17,
  nextEarnings: '2020-10-18',
  eps: 3.3888
]
```

I have tried `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` but it just returns an error with the syntax, what is the best way about going with it, my pool query also looks like this:

```
var query = pool.query(
          `INSERT INTO advancedstats(symbol, beta, debtequity, dividendyield, peratio, employees,
          pricebook, psratio, putcallratio, revenueshare, enterprisevaluerevenue, nextearnings, 
          eps) VALUES($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13)`,
          newData
        );
```

where `newData` is the current object

Comment: Your desired output is invalid. Arrays only have members, you cannot have `key: value` pairs in them

Comment: JS does not support your needed output

Comment: Looking at the [`pool.query`](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#poolquery) documentation you probably want to do: `pool.query("query here ...", [obj.symbol, obj.beta, obj.debtEquity, ...])` where `obj` is your current object.

Answer (score 0):

If looking - more likely yes - to array output like this:

```
[
  'AAPL',
  1.1792937836342379,
  1.19,
  0.006304622435881964,
  37.02,
  142011,
  24.66992282382262,
  7.9,
  0.845692355591619,
  15.22,
  8.17,
  '2020-10-18',
  3.3888
]
```

you can use `Object.values(variable)` to transform object to such array. However, this operation would not guarantee the order of variables - it would be important for your case. To enforce order I would suggest a function that takes data object, and array with properties names (in order) loop true properties and build result.

So with:

```
const propertyOrder = ['symbol', 'beta', 'debtEquity', ......];
const results = propertyOrder.map((key) => obj[key]);
```

Comment: To grantee a certain value order create an array of property names, then map them to their corresponding values. `const propOrder = ["symbol", "beta", ...]` then `const values = propOrder.map(name => obj[name])`